# How do I return a populated model when using a group by in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I was wondering if there is a way to do the following in a single query?

```
1) non_populated_models = PropertyPerson.select("property_people.id, count('items.recipient_person_id')").joins(:items).group('items.recipient_person_id, property_people.id')
2) populated_models = PropertyPerson.where(id: [non_populated_models])
```

Currently, the first group by query only returns the id, and count in the ProperyPerson object.  Let's say there were 15 fields in the model and I didn't want to explicitly write them all out.  Is there a way I can do this operation in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join will work to limit the query to `property_people` with `item` and you you will get the extra column as an `attr_reader`.

```
people = PropertyPerson.select("property_people.*,
                                count('items.recipient_person_id') as items_count")
                       .joins(:items)
                       .group("property_people.id")

people.first.item_count
```